# My program is doing some weird stuff

Tags: java, eclipse

So here is my assignment objective:

> Suppose the weekly hours for all employees are stored in a
>   two-dimensional array. Each row records an employee’s n-day work hours
>   with n columns where n ≥ 1 and n ≤ 7 representing the number of days
>   in a week that these employees work. For example, the table shown
>   below represents an array that stores the work hours of eight
>   employees for 7 days in a week. Write a program that takes in as
>   inputs, the number of employees and the number of working days in a
>   week. Then it takes in all the Employee information (name and number
>   of daily hours worked). This program should display employees and
>   their total hours worked in a week in decreasing order of the total
>   hours.

The output should look something like this:

```
Employee 7 worked 39 hours
Employee 6 worked 37 hours
Employee 0 worked 34 hours
Employee 4 worked 32 hours
Employee 3 worked 31 hours
Employee 1 worked 28 hours
Employee 5 worked 28 hours
Employee 2 worked 24 hours
```

Also, the output should be in decreasing order of most hours worked to least...

My code is being weird and giving me "null" in my output and it also won't show how many hours each employee worked after I put them in...

Here is my code:

```
package assignment3TL;

import java.util.*;

public class EmployeeWorkHours {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner turtle = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] calender = {"S", "M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "S"};
        System.out.println("How many Employee's do you have?: ");
        int NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES = turtle.nextInt();
        turtle.nextLine();
        int[][] hours;
        hours = new int[NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES][7];
        String[][] employee = new String[NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES][2];

        // input for Names
        for (int x = 0; x < (employee.length); x++) {
            System.out.println("Name of Employee " + (x + 1) + ": ");
            String name = turtle.nextLine();
            employee[x][1] = name;

        }
        // input for Hours
        for (int z = 0; z < hours.length; z++) {
            System.out.println("Starting from Sunday, enter the hours Employee " + (z + 1) + " has worked each day (Make sure you seperate it by spaces): ");
            for (int a = 0; a < (hours[0].length); a++) {
                hours[z][a] = turtle.nextInt();
            }
        }
        // Print everything out
        for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < employee[0].length; z++) {
                System.out.println(employee[i][z] + "-");
            }
            for (int f = 0; f < NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES; f++) {

                System.out.println(" " + hours[i][f]);

            }
        }
        // Total hours.
        for (int s = 0; s < hours[0].length; s++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int d = 0; d < hours.length; d++) {
                hours[d][s] += counter;
            }
            System.out.println("Employee " + (s + 1) + " worked " + counter + "   hours.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where else do I need to clear the newline at?

Comment: I tried clearing turtle.nextLine on line 12 after **int NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES = turtle.nextInt();** but that is giving me an error when I run it...

Comment: So I've taken a slightly closer look...that `nextLine` wouldn't be of any use to you here.   There are quite a few things going awry here, but my question to you is, why do you need to use a two-dimension array for `employee` when you only ever use one dimension of it ever?

Comment: So how can I get it to implement using two-dimensional arrays instead of just one then?

Comment: "My program is doing some weird stuff" - Probably the worst non-question ever posted to a Q&A site... I mean, nevermind that it isn't a question; this title gives no context or useful information whatsoever...-1 until fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your current code. Apart from capturing `nextline` and the two dimensional array problem for your `employee`, the whole logic to print the desired output is wrong. Also the for loop conditions are simply wrong and won't get the desired output. So the program isn't doing any weird stuff - you just coded it wrong.

You should try this updated code:

```
      Scanner turtle = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] calender = { "S", "M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "S" };
      System.out.println("How many Employee's do you have?: ");
      int NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES = turtle.nextInt();
      turtle.nextLine();

      int [][]hours;
      int []totalHours= new int[NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES];

      hours = new int[NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES][7];
      String[] employee = new String[NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES];

      // input for Names
      for (int x = 0; x < (employee.length); x++) {
          System.out.println("Name of Employee " + (x + 1) + ": ");
          String name = turtle.nextLine();
          employee[x] = name;

      }
      // input for Hours
      for (int z = 0; z < employee.length; z++) {
          System.out.println("Starting from Sunday, enter the hours Employee "+ (z + 1)+ " has worked each day (Make sure you seperate it by spaces): ");
          for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
              hours[z][a] = turtle.nextInt();
          }
          turtle.nextLine();
     }
      // Print everything out
      for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
          totalHours[i]=0;
          for(int j=0; j<7; j ++){
              totalHours[i] = totalHours[i]+hours[i][j];   
          }

        System.out.println("Employee " + (i + 1) +" worked " + totalHours[i] + " hours");  

      }
```

Also note, that I have added `totalHours` array and played around with it to get the final output.

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow. I hate when the little things make so much sense afterwards... Thank you so much. Do you have any ways to make the output in decreasing order?

Comment: @tylorton2 not sure what you are asking

Comment: My program at the end when it displays how many hours total each employee worked should also list the total hours of employee in decreasing order, meaning the employee with the most hours listed first, and the employee with the least hours listed last..

Comment: @tylorton2 I would recommend you to play around with `totalHours` for same and create logic around that. That's the way you will be able to learn about the silly mistakes which everyone makes and will also help you in future to tackle same sort of problems. If after putting in effort, you still don't get it then you can come back to SO and ask the question. Good luck

Comment: I looked around to see what I could find and I know that I need to use Arrays.sort(a,Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: I tried to use Arrays.sort(totalHours, Collections.reverseOrder()); but it is giving me this error on that line, "The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[], Collections.reverseOrder())"

Comment: @tylorton2 That will reverse for `totalHours` but how will you know which emplyee is it associated with?

Comment: Dang I didn't think of that.... So would I put it in the very last System.out.println? I'm not too sure....

Comment: @tylorton2 Nope. You just need to think of some other way. May be update your existing code

Comment: @tylorton2 Create a new question with your doubts and mention about your efforts so far